# What is the difference between 'git push foo bar -f' and 'git push foo +bar'?

Tags: git, syntax, branch, push

What the title says.  When rebasing, I've always been told to avoid forcing the push and to use + on the local branch instead.  Anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[git-push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

The difference i that with + you are forcing only the branch having this prefix, and with -f you are forcing all branches that are specified on the push

In both cases (-f and +) you may loose someone's commits on the server side, so probably the idea behind the advise is that if you haven't pulled master and made a push with all matching branches then -f would ruin someone's work on the server, as not only your own branch would be reset remotely.

In any case you should very rarely make a forced update in an environment when there are multiple repository users, as anyone having your branch checked out would have issues updating.

Comment: "with -f you are forcing all branches" does it mean when using `-f`, specifying a branch is useless ?

Comment: of course not, -f doesn't guess branches. It _applies_ to all branches that you specify in the push. But as long as there may be wildcard branch specifiers, this may apply to many branches at once, as in `git push -f origin :`

Comment: Ok, so `git push -f origin master` will still force push only `master` (even if there are other branches both in local and in remote) to `origin` ?

Comment: yes, only master. But it is a bad idea to force push master, unless you are the only user of the repository, or you have all agreed that this is the right thing to do

Comment: "it is a bad idea to force push master" I couldn't agree more. Since `git push -f origin master` will only force push `master`, I can't get the real use of `+` (isn't it the same ?)

Comment: yes, in this particular case the commands do exactly the same thing

Comment: Thanks for your explanations

Comment: you should consider accepting this answer if it clarifies your question